# Get Element by Position determined in Z-Index - Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, position

I am using the following sentence to get the element in some position, but he takes the first ...

```
$(this.cTaskItem[0]).mouseup(function(event){
    var posX = event.clientX, posY = event.clientY;
    var overElem = document.elementFromPoint(posX, posY);
    overElem.style.border = "3px solid red";
});
```

I wonder how do I get the element at a given position and Z-Index.

Thank You

Comment: You mean there are two elements above each other (different z-indexes) at a point and you want to get the lower one?

Comment: Where is your question..??

Comment: But why would you want to do that? Sounds like an [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) - please [edit] your question to include more information

Comment: What happens is this, I have a series of DIV's stacked, the way you put the question I seem to get only the first, I need to catch the second from the bottom up.

Comment: well one thing you could try (not tested) is to hide the found element, do the `elementFromPoint` again until you reach the `body`. then (if this works) you would have them in z-order, and you could choose the right one, and show the others again.

Comment: It worked for me as I have little objects, was not slow ..

thank you

Answer (score 1):

If the first element (the one that's selected by `document.elementFromPoint(posX, posY)`) is not supposed to be clickable you can set the css prepoerty `pointer-events: none;` to it and it will not be selected anymore

Answer (score 0):

As @t.niese suggested above you could do this:

```
$(this.cTaskItem[0]).mouseup(function(event)
{
    var posX = event.clientX, posY = event.clientY;
    var elements = [];
    var elm = document.elementFromPoint(posX, posY);
    while(elm.tagName != "HTML")
    {
        elements.push(elm);
        elm.style.display = "none";
        elm = document.elementFromPoint(posX, posY);
    }
```

});

Then all you would need to do is go through your `elements` array and select the one you need.

Comment: $("body").click(function(e){
    var x = e.pageX, y = e.pageY;
    var res = [];
    
    var ele = document.elementFromPoint(x,y);
    while(ele && ele.tagName != "BODY" && ele.tagName != "HTML"){
        res.push(ele);
        ele.style.display = "none";
        ele = document.elementFromPoint(x,y);
    }
    
    for(var i = 0; i < res.length; i++){
        res[i].style.display = "block";
    }
    console.log(res);
});